# Dividir cadenas con expresiones regulares

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Buenas quiero extraer en cadenas separadas un string con Jquery no se si hacerlo con expresiones regulares o algún otro método, la cadena es la es la siguiente

```
?i=0&edad=18_28&tarifa=40_80,81_110&servicio=25&ubicacion=1,4
```

Más que todo extraer las cadenas que se encuentran entre los & y guardarlas en variables o array osea que quede de la siguiente forma:

```
id=0
edad=18_28
tarifa=40_48,81_110
servicio=25
ubicacion=1,4
```

Tomando en cuenta que NO siempre estarán todas aveces, puede estar edad y tarifa pero no ubicación, por favor ayuda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

aquí te dejo un ejemplo de como puedes hacer. Tienes diferentes formatos de salida para que puedas elegir el mas indicado para tu caso. Saludos!

```js
const url = new URL('http://midominio.com/ruta/?param1=valor1&param2=valor2&param3=valor3')



const searchParams = url.searchParams

const keys = [...searchParams.keys()]

const object1 = keys
  .reduce((obj, key) =>({...obj, [key]: searchParams.get(key) }), {})
  
const object2 = [...searchParams.entries()]
  .reduce((obj, [key, value]) => ({...obj, [key]: value }), {})

console.log(object1)
console.log(object2)

// [[key1, value1], ...]
console.log([...searchParams.entries()])
// [key1, key2, ...]
console.log([...searchParams.keys()])
// [value1, value2, ...]
console.log([...searchParams.values()])
```